# Specify timeframe daily for ATR

Tags: pine-script

i'm a beginner with Pinescript.
I have to use 30% of ATR daily but i'm using a 30 min timeframe.
I've tried to settle it as reported here below but something is missing..
Could anyone please help me?
Thanks a lot!

```
// STEP 5:
// During the session, update that session's existing box
if inSession
    box.set_top(sessionBox, sessionHighPrice)
    box.set_bottom(sessionBox, sessionLowPrice)

    box.set_right(sessionBox, bar_index + 1)

    // See if sessionBox higher than 30% of ATR daily. When it did, make
    // box green (and use red otherwise).
    
    if sessionHighPrice - sessionHighPrice > ta.atr(5) * 0.3
        box.set_bgcolor(sessionBox, upBoxColor)
        box.set_border_color(sessionBox, upBorderColor)
    else
        box.set_bgcolor(sessionBox, downBoxColor)
        box.set_border_color(sessionBox, downBorderColor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function to get data from other timeframes.

```
atr_daily = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ta.atr(14))
```